# missing group label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I want to add grouped label instead of individual label in `ggplot` using `stat_summaryh`. My data is like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   id2 small_oe xinterceptm startidm endidm medium_oe medium_region
1    1       NA           1        1      1        NA          <NA>
                  2    2     1.66          NA        1      4      1.36        FL-M-4
                  3    3     1.21          NA        1      4      1.36        FL-M-4
                  4    4       NA           4        4      4        NA          <NA>
                  5    5     1.34          NA        4      7      1.17        FL-M-5
                  6    6     0.97          NA        4      7      1.17        FL-M-5
                  7    7       NA           7        7      7        NA          <NA>
                  8    8     1.21          NA        7     10      1.19       FL-M-14
                  9    9     0.91          NA        7     10      1.19       FL-M-14
                  10  10       NA          10       10     10        NA          <NA>
                  11  11     1.34          NA       10     13      1.17       FL-M-13
                  12  12     0.96          NA       10     13      1.17       FL-M-13
                  13  13       NA          13       13     13        NA          <NA>
                  14  14     1.30          NA       13     16      1.20        NY-M-4
                  15  15     1.18          NA       13     16      1.20        NY-M-4
                  16  16       NA          16       16     16        NA          <NA>
                  17  17     0.87          NA       16     18      0.87        NY-M-5
                  18  18       NA          18       18     18        NA          <NA>
                  19  19     1.09          NA       18     20      1.09        NE-M-5
                  20  20       NA          20       20     20        NA          <NA>
                  21  21     1.60          NA       20     22      1.60        FL-M-3
                  22  22       NA          22       22     22        NA          <NA>
                  23  23     1.14          NA       22     25      1.14        FL-M-1
                  24  24     1.12          NA       22     25      1.14        FL-M-1
                  25  25       NA          25       25     25        NA          <NA>
                  26  26     0.71          NA       25     27      0.71        FL-M-2
                  27  27       NA          27       27     27        NA          <NA>
                  28  28     1.16          NA       27     29      1.16       FL-M-12
                  29  29       NA          29       29     29        NA          <NA>
                  30  30     1.14          NA       29     31      1.15       FL-M-11",
                  header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

When I tried adding labels to each group in `ggplot`, some of the groups' labels were missing. (The plot and my code are attached here) How can I fix that?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = id2, y = small_oe)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),   ## adjust the theme: clean background, remove x-axis labels/values
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xinterceptm), linetype = "dotted", alpha = 0.3) +  ## add vertical lines seperating median cluster groups
  geom_segment(aes(x = startidm, xend = endidm, y= medium_oe, yend = medium_oe), alpha = 0.4) + ## add line segments as median region o:e
  stat_summaryh(fun.x = mean, aes(label = medium_region, y = medium_oe+0.02), geom = "text", size = 3, alpha = 0.4, color = "blue")
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`dat$medium_region` contains NA's, thus the blank labels. You should change them to something appropriate.

```
dat$medium_region <- gsub("<NA>", "Unknown", dat$medium_region)
```

May be an appropriate way to rename all NA's, if they don't have a name but you would like a label to display.

### Solution:

So I think those two labels are unhappy about being in the same y-plane (`medium_oe` value), so you could add a vector to move specifically those two labels out of alignment. 
Create a new column called mod and alter the value:

```
dat$mod <- 0
dat$mod[dat$mod$medium_region == FL-M-5] <- 0.01
```

Then alter the stat_summaryh argument to:

```
y = medium_oe + 0.02 + mod
```

This works in your example data, but mod would need changing for specific overlapping samples in other datasets. Not ideal, but I don't understand why they can't share the same y coord.

It likely has something to do with this warning:

```
4: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

Comment: Actually I tried filled the blanks in medium_region with the non-missing labels using `fill` in `tidyr` package, but the labels are still missing. I don't think it's a problem of NA's, because other regions were labelled perfectly with NAs

Comment: So I see -  FL-M-5 and -13 are missing. Do you get the following warnings when you run it?
`Warning messages:
1: Removed 12 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summaryh). 
2: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_vline). 
3: Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_segment). 
4: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is only with FL-M-5 and FL-M-13, because they have exactly the same `medium_oe` (1.17). If you remove one, the other's label shows up fine, e.g. if you sub `foo` and `bar` into `dat` in your original plot-

```
foo = dat[c(1:3,7:nrow(dat)),]
bar = dat[c(1:9,13:nrow(dat)),]
```

This causes a problem because `stat_summaryh` is trying to place a label at the mean `id2` for each unique value of `medium_oe` with the label corresponding to that `medium_oe`. But there are two unique values for `medium_oe == 1.17`. So it does not place a label there.

Another thing I noticed is that your plot is labeled such that the y-axis is supposed to be `small_oe`. However, you're plotting the segments with y-values at `medium_oe`, which doesn't look to be the mean of the two `small_oe` values. So you should definitely make sure this plot is showing what you intend it to.

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact problem that caused the incomplete labeling issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of Tyr, I provided a detailed solution here:

### 1.Replace the duplicated values in groups

My original data has lots of groups so I need to write code to find the duplicated values **automatically** instead of manually typing the region names:

```
### group by medium region
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(medium_region) %>%
  summarize(
    mean_mediumoe = mean(medium_oe, na.rm = T)
  )

### find regions with duplicated oe values 
duplicated(dat2$mean_mediumoe)

### create new var = slightly different value if the values are not unique 
dat2$medium_oe2 <- ifelse(duplicated(dat2$mean_mediumoe) == TRUE, dat2$mean_mediumoe+0.0001, dat2$mean_mediumoe)

### merge data and keep original ordering 
dat3 <- merge(dat, dat2, by.x = "medium_region")

dat3 <- arrange(dat3, id2)
```

### 2. Draw plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(dat3, aes(x = id2, y = small_oe)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),   ## adjust the theme: clean background, remove x-axis labels/values
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xinterceptm), linetype = "dotted", alpha = 0.3) +  ## add vertical lines seperating median cluster groups
  geom_segment(aes(x = startidm, xend = endidm, y= medium_oe, yend = medium_oe), alpha = 0.4) + ## add line segments as median region o:e
  stat_summaryh(fun.x = mean, aes(label = medium_region, y = medium_oe2+0.02), geom = "text", size = 3, alpha = 0.4, color = "blue")
```

Now every group has it's labels. [image]